# apollo-server-express: how to resolve inside subscriptions?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

When doing regular graphQL queries, I have no trouble to get nested objects or computations. **But when inside a subscription like**:

```
subscription {
  Event(filter: {
    mutation_in: [CREATED]
  }) {
    node {
      title
      description
      start
      end
      seats
      bookings
      owner {
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It breaks as soon as I add `bookings` or `owner { ... }`. I see no error message on then server. QraphiQL only displays a `[object Object]` as a response.

## The interesing par of the schema is:

```
type Event {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  owner: User!
  seats: Int
  bookings: Int
  start: DateTime!
  end: DateTime!
  tickets: [EventTicket!]!
}


type Mutation {
  createEvent(event: EventInput!): Event
}
input EventInput {
  title: String!
  description: String!
  seats: Int
  start: DateTime!
  end: DateTime!
}


type Subscription {
  Event(filter: EventSubscriptionFilter): EventSubscriptionPayload
}
input EventSubscriptionFilter {
  mutation_in: [_ModelMutationType!]
}
type EventSubscriptionPayload {
  mutation: _ModelMutationType!
  node: Event
}
enum _ModelMutationType {
  CREATED
  UPDATED
  DELETED
}
```

## And the resolvers:

```js
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb"
import pubsub from "../../utils/pubsub"

export default {
  // ...
  Mutation: {
    createEvent: async (_, data, { mongo: { Events }, user }) => {
      const newEvent = data.event
      newEvent.ownerId = user._id
      const response = await Events.insert(newEvent)
      const [_id] = response.insertedIds
      newEvent._id = _id
      pubsub.publish("Event", { Event: { mutation: "CREATED", node: newEvent } })
      return newEvent
    },
  },
  Subscription: {
    Event: {
      subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator("Event"),
    },
  },
  Event: {
    id: event => event._id.toString(),
    owner: async (event, _, { mongo: { Users } }) => Users.findOne({ _id: event.ownerId }),
    bookings: async (event, _, { mongo: { EventTickets } }) =>
      EventTickets.find({ eventId: event._id }).count(),
    tickets: async (event, _, { mongo: { EventTickets } }) =>
      EventTickets.find({ eventId: event._id }).toArray(),
  },
}
```

Any idea about how to deal with this (and/or how to get a proper error message to debug ^^).

Answer (score 1):

Ok after searching, [I found the solution/hack here](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/issues/306#issuecomment-348695199).

```
    SubscriptionServer.create(
        {
           execute, subscribe, schema,
           onOperation: (message, params, webSocket) => {
            return { ...params, context: {mongo} }
          },
        },
        { server, path: '/subscriptions' },
    );
```

Thanks [nharraud](https://github.com/nharraud).